# How to test several predictors' effect when you use means and standard deviations (or SE) from published papers?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, mean, meta-analysis, r-squared

For explanatory purposes, I will give a fake example to understand my question (and goal). Let's suppose I get from different published papers data about the concentration of a substance (`subst.concent`) depending on age (`age`) and if they are smokers or non-smokers (`smoking`). Following this example, I find that for `smokers`, the concentration of that substance increase as age increase, while for `non-smokers` there is no effect. Here a graph of what I find with my actual data (but modified to the "smokers" example):

[image]

I would like to test the effect of both `age` and `smoking` in `subst.concent`. I would expect to find a significant interaction between `age` and `smoking`. I tried a linear regression using the mean of each "population", however, I don't think this is the most appropriate since it doesn't consider the SD and for instance, the model gives an `R²` of 1, when I guess all the variance is not explained by my two variables.

How could I test the `age` and `smoking` effect in my `subst.concent` and the magnitude of their effect using both the mean and the SD?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Do you have a single mean from each paper? Or do papers report multiple means? In the latter case, are these cross-sectional studies, such that the 15 year old subjects are not the same people as the 25 year old subjects or are these longitudinal studies such that the same group of people was measured when they were 15 and when they were 25? (I assume that there is no overlap between smokers and non-smokers or can the same subject also appear in both of these groups?)

Comment: Thanks for your time @Wolfgang. Regarding your first question, I have one single mean per combination of levels. That is, for instance, for non-smokers being 15 years old one mean value, for non-smokers being 25 years old, another mean value, etc. All data comes maybe from 6/7 papers, so, in some of them, I have several means. Regarding if the studies are cross-sectional, yes, they are not longitudinal. They take different people for each group. And regarding overlapping within the `smoking` variable, no, they are different subjects for `smokers` and `non-smokers`.

Comment: @Wolfgang, Did you think something?

Comment: Isn't *meta-analysis* one approach to addressing your question? A search on CV for meta-analysis produced over 1,000 hits.

Comment: It might be, however, since I am new on that, I didn't know if someone could shed light on that saying specifically which method should be the best. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Another question: Do you also have a sample size for each measurement of the concentration?

Comment: @Wolfgang Yes!! I forgot it. But it is unbalanced. The older, the lower the size. But the size in any case is quite large (more than 1000 in the worst case for each age-smoking group).

Comment: Have you tried writing to the authors to see if you can get the full data of interest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can address this from a meta-analytic perspective. Let $y_{ij}$ be the observed concentration and $\mbox{SD}_{ij}$ and $n_{ij}$ the corresponding SD and sample size for the $i$th study and $j$th group within the study (so for a particular age and smoking status). Some studies may just report the results for a single group, which is fine. Then $v_{ij} = \mbox{SD}_{ij}^2 / n_{ij}$ is the estimated sampling variance of $y_{ij}$ if we assume that the concentration values are like means. Also, let $\mbox{age}_{ij}$ and $\mbox{smoke}_{ij}$ denote the age and smoking status (coded 0/1) for the groups.

Once you have estimates with corresponding sampling variances (and possibly some predictor variables), you can think of this as a meta-analysis. However, your data have a multilevel structure (since you have studies reporting concentration values for multiple groups), so you should use a multilevel meta-analytic model. Such a model is described by Konstantopoulos (2011). An example illustrating the analysis of such data is given here:

http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:konstantopoulos2011

In your case, think "study = district" and "group = school". Then you also want to add age and smoking status as predictors to the model (and maybe their interaction). You can also model non-linear associations for the age variable (e.g., using polynomials or splines).

**References**

Konstantopoulos, S. (2011). Fixed effects and variance components estimation in three-level meta-analysis. *Research Synthesis Methods, 2*(1), 61-76.

Comment: Thank you very much @Wolfgang. You gave me a clue to follow. I will look at the reference and follow your instructions. Thanks for your time.